# How to programmatically check if user is federated in Office 365?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, active-directory, office365

My application changes password in Office 365 account. However a user is federated (i.e. there is a sync between an on premise AD and O365 (WAAD)), it is not (or limited) allowed to change data in O365 because it should be done in the on premise AD.

How i can check in my code if user federated or not?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm looking to do the sane.

Comment: Yes, see the comment below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible way to check if the user is federated or not could be via:

```
POST
https://login.microsoftonline.com/GetUserRealm.srf
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept: application/json
handler=1&login=johndoe@somecompany.onmicrosoft.com
```